# Como autenticar cliente com biblioteca SSL do python?

Tags: python, segurança, autenticação, ssl, openssl

Estou fazendo um servidor de mensagens p2p e quero autenticar usuários. Ao procurar na internet, encontrei isso aqui:

```py
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED;#
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=ca_bundle);
context.check_hostname = False;
```

De acordo com o [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_REQUIRED) a primeira linha forçaria uma [autenticação de cliente](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-tls-client-auth/) mandatória. A segunda linha carrega o bundle de certificados para autenticação do certificado em questão. A terceira linha é apenas por que minha rede usa IP dinâmico, então eu uso identificadores como "common name" na hora de gerar os certificados, então eu uso essa linha para evitar que verifique o IP do certificado.

Eu consigo gerar os certificados sem problema, mas queria ter certeza que estou implementando o protocolo corretamente, isto é, esse código acima está certo?

Caso contrário, teria alguma biblioteca capaz de lidar desse tipo de conexão? Ou seria melhor eu implementar o protocolo eu mesmo?

**Qualquer comentário é bem vindo!**

Essa aqui é a minha tentativa:

**cliente**

```py
import socket, ssl, sys
import time
client_number = "5502199999999";#eu uso números de celular como 'common name'
CERT_AU = "arquiv_com_certificado_da_CA.pem"
CERT_1 = "arquivo_com_o_certificado_do_cliente.pem"
KEY = "arquivo_com_a_chave_privada_do_cliente.pem"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET);
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH);
context.set_ciphers('EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH')
context.check_hostname = False;
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT_1, keyfile=KEY)
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=CERT_AU);
conn = context.wrap_socket(sock);

x1 = time.perf_counter();
conn.connect(('192.168.0.107', 50052));
resposta = conn.recv();
resposta = resposta.decode('UTF-8');
if resposta == "???":
    conn.write(bytes(sys.argv[1],"utf-8"));
    resposta = conn.recv();
    conn.close();
```

**servidor**

```py
import ssl, socket, sys
from threading import *
from _thread import *
from datetime import datetime

sock = socket.socket();
sock.bind(('', port_ssl));
sock.listen(5);
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH);
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=my_cert, keyfile=private_key);
'''
As próximas 3 linhas são utilizadas para obrigar o cliente a enviar
seu próprio certificado, o qual o script vai checar para ver se é efetivamente válido dado o ca_bundle oferecido.
Mais detalhes: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
'''
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED;#
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=ca_bundle);
context.check_hostname = False;
'''
Não usamos o check_hostname pq ele é voltado para IP e acaba dando um erro (Ele verifica o IP local fornecido)
'''
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # optional
context.set_ciphers('EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH')

file = open("client_1.txt", "a");
file.write("conexao_ssl iniciou\n-----------\n");
file.close();

while True:
    ssock, addr = sock.accept();

    start_new_thread(recebimento_individual, (ssock, context));

print("Servidor desligando!");

def recebimento_individual(ssock, context):
    try:    
        print("=================");
        conn = context.wrap_socket(ssock, server_side=True);
        '''
        Pegando o 'common name' do certificado, isto é, o nome do
        do dono do certificado.
        '''
        cert = conn.getpeercert(binary_form=False);
        cert_name = cert['subjectAltName'][0][1];
        print(cert_name);
        '''
        Essas duas linhas indicam para o remetente que conexão foi aceita e que podemos receber a mensagem.
        '''
        conn.write(bytes("???","utf-8"));
        x = conn.recv().decode('UTF-8');
        
        lock.acquire();
        file = open("client_1.txt", "a");
        file.write(str(datetime.now()) + ":::" + cert_name + ":::" + x);
        file.write("\n");
        file.close();
        lock.release();

    except ssl.SSLError as e:
        print("==receber==\n");
        print(e);

    except Exception as e:
        print(e);

    finally:
        conn.close()
```

A minha pergunta é se essas duas linhas aqui:

```py
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED;#
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=ca_bundle);
```

Fazem a verificação completa do certificado do cliente. Isto é, se elas analisam a assinatura do cliente e determinam que ele tem a **chave privada correspondente a chave pública** do certificado.

Eu quero fazer isso para autenticar meus usuários.

Nesse meio tempo eu encontrei [esse](https://gist.github.com/nebulak/6d865ddd768fb905a562d6026cdd508a) que eu acho que comprova isso, mas eu queria uma fonte mais oficial.

Qualquer comentário é bem vindo

Comment: Você está perguntando sem nem mesmo ter tentado implementar? Creio que podemos ajudar uma vez que você tenha feito a implementação da autenticação e, caso obtenha algum erro/dúvida, criar uma pergunta direta a respeito do que precisa.

Comment: Eu implementei, vou copiar e colocar o código aqui. Só não tenho certeza se é realmente isso.

Answer (score 1):

Após muita pesquisa, finalmente encontrei um [exemplo](https://www.ppgia.pucpr.br/%7Ejamhour/Pessoal/Graduacao/Ciencia/SocketsC/sslpython.html) (*antigo*) do uso do módulo SSL do python para autenticação de cliente:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import ssl

host_addr = '127.0.0.1'
host_port = 9001
hostname = 'www.ugtransportes.com.br'
server_cert = 'server.crt'
client_cert = 'client.crt'
client_key = 'client.key'

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile=server_cert)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=client_cert, keyfile=client_key)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=False, server_hostname=hostname)
ssock.connect((host_addr, host_port))

ssock.send(b"Mensagem do cliente 1")

ssock.close()
```

Salvo engano, acredito que meus exemplos de cliente/servidor estão corretos. Agradeço a ajuda.